# Foreach not working in a while loop?

Tags: php

I have a MySQL database and I use a while loop to take information from it. I also have an array that I want to loop though with foreach, but the problem is when I try to nest foreach in while there is no data in $strings. The $string variable works outside of the while loop, and there is nothing wrong with the database. What do I need to change so I can loop through both?

```
while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
foreach($string as $strings)
{
//code here
}
}
```

Comment: Nested looping isn't the problem. Something is wrong with what is stored in `$string`. Also shouldn't you have it as `$strings as $string`?.

Comment: Even though you meant it the other way around, I still would never use "string" as a variable name.  Maybe it works.  But I just wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, if the problem isn't with the loop, then I'll just debug other things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for-loop is wrong. The array should come first.

```
  foreach($strings as $string)
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure my for-loop is correct. The array does come first. $string is the array, although of course I use $strings inside the loop. Or am I wrong?

Comment: So you got an array named `string` and each item in it you name `strings`? In that case, the code is right, but your naming is very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the problem is in the loop after all. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSawatzky Thumbs up for intuitive and precise variable names! :)