# How to put a foreach in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out how to use a foreach in my while loop.

I already tried to understand these posts but I couldn't figure out:

[Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005636/a-foreach-loop-in-a-while-loop)

[Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828784/foreach-not-working-in-a-while-loop)

I've also tried to find it on other sites(like w3).

This is my code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table class='table'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>security</th>
    <th>photo</th>
    </tr>";
    // output data of each row
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Date"]."</td>
        <td>" . $row["Security"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Photo"]. "</td>
        </tr></table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I get only one row from the database table and the others are outputted like this:

2019-09-12 15:24:23 0 6 2019-09-12 15:30:09 1 7 2019-09-12 15:30:33 1 8 2019-09-12 15:30:33 1 9 2019-09-12 15:30:33 1 10 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 11 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 12 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 13 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 14 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 15 2019-09-12 15:32:39 1 16 2019-09-12 19:26:36 1 17 2019-09-12 19:26:42 1 18 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 19 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 20 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 21 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 22 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 23 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 24 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 25 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 26 2019-09-12 19:35:15 1 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change code like below:-

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);//get query error if occur
    $rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //use fetch_all()
?>
<table class='table'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>security</th>
        <th>photo</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            foreach($rows as $row) { //apply foreach()
    ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["id"] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Date"] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Security"] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Photo"] ;?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php
            }
        } else {
    ?>
        <tr colspan="4">No data found</tr>
    <?php
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use foreach with [fetch-all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) method

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?> 
   <table class='table'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>security</th>
    <th>photo</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // output data of each row
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
         ?>
       <tr>
        <td><?=  $row["id"];?></td>
        <td><?=  $row["Date"];?></td>
        <td><?=  $row["Security"];?></td>
        <td><?=  $row["Photo"];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```